# php regex match word and stop

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a URL like this `http://website.com/clothes/men/type/t-shirts/color/red/size/xl...` and I need to perform an action when the url is like this `http://website.com/clothes/(men or woman)/type/any-type`

So if the after `type/any-type` there are other values I don't want to perform the action.

My regex looks like this right now `preg_match('/clothes\/(men|women)\/type\/(.*)\/?$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

It matches the case I want, but it also matches if the URL continues after that specific key/value pair, so it also matches `http://website.com/clothes/men/type/t-shirts/color/red`.

So in the end I need the `preg_match()` to only match a URL that has only a `type/anything` pair.

Thank you.

Comment: Really, just use a router like https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute

Comment: The project is almost done and it's all done with .htaccess and it works very well, so for now I'm sticking with it. My question was about regex, but thank you anyway.

Comment: It was just a suggestion, I'm always afraid of .htaccess monsters, but see below for my answer.

Comment: I don't mind using .htaccess at all, but I will take into consideration using FastRoute, it's not the first time it has been suggested to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just match `[^/]+`:

```
preg_match('(clothes/(men|women)/type/([^/]+)/?$)', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
if ( preg_match('~/clothes/(?:wo)?men/type/[^/]+/$~i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $m) ) {
   // matches succeeds
}
```

1. You can use alternate delimiter like `~` to avoid escaping every forward slash
2. Remove `.*` in the end if you don't want to match after `.../type/any-type/`

Comment: Thanks for the point 1, didn't know that. The language is not english, but I like `(?:wo)?men` thing. Always helpful, thanks again

Comment: Hope this regex works for you, if not let me know and I will tweak it.

Comment: It works, but I decided to go with the one posted by @bwoebi, just because is shorter.

Comment: May I know where exactly it is shorter? Mine looks longer only because I included `if ` and `{` etc.